# try and except for value error and name error

Tags: python

The beginning of the program I'm trying to write asks for input between 0.0 and 1.0. The code has been successful in handling incorrect input outside of this range. However, I also want to print a statement for incorrect output when letters or special character are inputted. I tried to do this with an except for value error and name error but it still says name error or value error instead of printing the error message I intended. Any advice would be much appreciated. Code below:

```
score = input('Enter Score: ')
try:
    gr = float(score)
    if gr > 1.0:
        print('Grade cannot be above 1')
        quit()
    if gr < 0: 
        print('Grade cannot be negative')
        quit()
except ValueError: 
    print('Input invalid')
except NameError: 
    print('Input invalid')
```

Comment: Not sure i follow. Could you add the output when you run it? Just by running the same, it works as expected for me (as far as i understand what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Just to be clear, [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) is only raised when trying to use a non-existent variable (which you don't do anywhere in your code).

Comment: When I run your code and put in a non-numeric value, I get "Input invalid".  I don't see a problem here except that you're never going to catch a `NameError` here...your last two lines are useless.

Comment: For some reason earlier, it was returning value error or name error instead of the intended message but I ran it again and it works now for some reason. Good to know that the name error code would not have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def validate_score(score=None):
    if score.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
        grade = float(score)
        if grade > 1:
            print('Grade cannot be above 1')
            return None
        elif grade < 0: 
            print('Grade cannot be below 0')
            return None
        else:
            return grade
    else:
        print('Grade is invalid')
        return None

def some_other_function(grade):
    print("My grade is:", grade)

score = input('Enter Score: ')
grade = validate_score(score)

if grade != None:
    some_other_function(grade)
```

I wrote function that satisfies your requirements, explanation:

1. Function `validate_score`:

   1. If score is a valid `float`:

      1. Turn score to `float`
      2. If grade is more than `1`:

         1. Warn user and return `None`
      3. If grade is less than `0`:

         1. Warn user and return `None`
      4. Else:

         1. Return `grade`
   2. Else:

      1. Warn user and return `None`

Try/Except is not necessary because you can validate `float` without them

Comment: I hadn't thought of creating a function to do this but it's not a bad idea. Thanks!